# Add a node into a split pane divider

Tags: javafx, splitpane

I'm trying to find a solution of how to add a label into a split pane divider or at least create the illusion of that. My approach was to add three panes into the split pane and drag the middle pane along with the two divider. The problem is that on rapid mouse movements the middle pane gets bigger, but if I define a max height then the dragging doesn't work at all.

My question is if there is a way of directly inserting a label onto the divider or if somebody has a better solution as mine to accomplish something like this.

## MWE:

**Class**

```
public class MainSplit extends Application {

    @FXML
    private SplitPane splitPane;

    @FXML
    private Pane dividerPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/splitpane.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        Parent root = loader.load();

        AtomicReference<Double> start = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
        dividerPane.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            start.set((1.0 / splitPane.getScene().getHeight()) * event.getSceneY());
        });

        dividerPane.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            double p = (1.0 / splitPane.getScene().getHeight()) * event.getSceneY();
            double diff = p - start.get();
            start.set(p);

            double[] d = splitPane.getDividerPositions();
            splitPane.setDividerPosition(0, d[0] + diff);
            splitPane.setDividerPosition(1, d[1] + diff);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<SplitPane fx:id="splitPane" dividerPositions="0.36, 0.43" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0"
           xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <AnchorPane/>
    <Pane fx:id="dividerPane" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4545;">
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="V_RESIZE"/>
        </cursor>
    </Pane>
    <AnchorPane/>
</SplitPane>
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom [skin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#skinProperty) ?

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it and see whats possible.